# Can Elasticsearch upserts delete fields in the target document and don't exist in the source document?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a document in ES, with a field called "field1", and I perform an upsert with a request that does not have "field1" in the document, is there a way of that upsert being able to remove the field in the target document?

So far, I can only see ES either add the field if it does not exist, or amended the field value if the value has changed.

I am using ES version 5.5.2.

Comment: Well, if the semantics of "no field" means "delete field", what about all other fields that are not in the update request, shall they get deleted from the document, too?

Comment: @Val Well that is kind of what I was thinking, but asked the question in case I was missing something.

Comment: You can still add some kind of parameter (`"_delete_fieldName": true`) than will convey the desired semantics and you can act on that in your script

Comment: T h a n ks @Val